# Android : check the CC email validation in text field

Tags: java, android

How to check cc email validation in text field
for space and should be seperated bu " ; "

private Boolean check_email_cc_validation() {

```
    Boolean status = true;

    if (edt_customer_cc.getText().length() != 0) {

        String str_to_split = edt_customer_cc.getText() + "";


        String split_array[] = str_to_split.split("\\;");


        for (String c : split_array) {

            c = c.trim();
            if (!c.isEmpty()) {
                if ((!isEmailValid(c))) {

                    edt_customer_cc.requestFocus();
                    edt_customer_cc.setError("Please enter valid email.");
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: String split_array[] = str_to_split.split("\\;");

Comment: __________1] String split_array[] = str_to_split.split("\\;")
- will split email 
__________2] c = c.trim(); 
- will trim (remove) space occuring , before and after email id.
 
__________3] if ((!isEmailValid(c))) {
- will check valid email 

__________4] boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {

return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
 // using built in function
}__________

Answer (score 0):

```
private Boolean check_email_cc_validation() {

    Boolean status = true;

    if (edt_customer_cc.getText().length() != 0) {

        String str_to_split = edt_customer_cc.getText() + "";


        String split_array[] = str_to_split.split("\\;");


        for (String c : split_array) {

            c = c.trim();
            if (!c.isEmpty()) {
                if ((!isEmailValid(c))) {

                    edt_customer_cc.requestFocus();
                    edt_customer_cc.setError("Please enter valid email.");
                    status = false;
                }
            }
        }


    }
    return status;
}
```

boolean isEmailValid(CharSequence email) {

```
    return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

will work fine..
just isEmailValid(CharSequence email) was missing